# How do I send app web requests through search engine links?

Tags: c#, discord, httpwebrequest, webrequest

So I'm trying to send a request to `discord:///invite/INVITECODE` in C# so it shows the popup in Discord inviting the user to my Discord server. However normal WebRequest / HttpWebRequests don't work since `discord:///` isn't a recognised URL prefix. How do I go about doing this?

Revision: I'm writing a C# .exe application and I simply want a button that executes that link so Discord opens in the same manner as it would by pasting that link into google.

Also, the "popup" is just what happens when you open Discord through that specific link, I wasnt implying that the request opens a popup. I'm sorry if the terminology is bad, I'm mostly self taught.

Comment: Why have you also tagged C? `HttpWebRequest` doesn't exist in C, and most C# code won't compile in C.

Comment: That does not make much sense - neither `WebRequest` nor any other way to execute web request in any language will "show the popup" of any kind... So not very clear what you want to achieve...

Comment: The user needs to execute that link using the protocol handler registered in their OS. Is the user running an installed app of your code (shellexecute...) ? Or fetching a web page from your server (<a href="">)?

Comment: Is 'discord' a real/valid protocol? I've never heard of it. What leads you think that is the URL you should use?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was to open the link in a WebBrowser.

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
Browser.Navigate("discord:///invite/invitecode");
```